# Handle CallBack from Facebook LikeView in Android

Tags: android, facebook-like, facebook-share

I am developing an Android App which will have both Fb `Like` & `Share` button. Till now I have added only the Like button. I want to do some stuffs whenever the user Likes (hits on Like button), so I need to register the `callback` methods. So I want know how to achieve that and also when hitting Like button, **Share** option is also show, so then how can I handle that too.

**Here are some piece of my code:**

```
LinearLayout btnLoginToLike;
LikeView likeView;
CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    initInstances();
    initCallbackManager();
    refreshButtonsState();
}

private void initInstances() {
    btnLoginToLike = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btnLoginToLike);
    likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.likeView);
    likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);
    likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);

    likeView.setObjectIdAndType(
            "http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en",
            LikeView.ObjectType.OPEN_GRAPH);

    btnLoginToLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
        }
    });
}

private void initCallbackManager() {
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            refreshButtonsState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    });
}

private void refreshButtonsState() {
    if (!isLoggedIn()) {
        btnLoginToLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        likeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        btnLoginToLike.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        likeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Handle Facebook Login Result
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**add some lines on your onActivityResults.**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras().getBundle("com.facebook.platform.protocol.RESULT_ARGS");
                if (bundle != null) {
                    Logger.LogInfo("Bundle", bundle.toString());
                    Boolean isLiked = bundle.getBoolean("object_is_liked"); // liked/unliked
                    Logger.LogInfo("object_is_liked", isLiked + "");
                    Integer isCompleted = bundle.getInt("didComplete");
                    Logger.LogInfo("didComplete", isCompleted + "");
                    Integer count = bundle.getInt("like_count"); // object like count
                    Logger.LogInfo("like_count", count + "");
                    String likeCount = bundle.getString("like_count_string");
                    Logger.LogInfo("like_count_string", likeCount + "");
                    String social = bundle.getString("social_sentence");
                    Logger.LogInfo("social_sentence", social + "");
                    String completeGesture = bundle.getString("completionGesture"); // liked/cancel/unliked
                    Logger.LogInfo("completionGesture", completeGesture + "");

                }
            }
```

}